# Регулярное выражения добавит строку

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Помогите добавить строку, например есть атрибут:

```
data-original="https://img.alicdn.com/imgextra/i3/1857444359/TB2j9N5aEafF1Jjy1XbXXaYiXXa_!!1857444359.jpg"
```

как добавить в конце ссылки эту строку: `_100x100.jpg` что бы получилось как то так:

`data-original="https://img.alicdn.com/imgextra/i3/1857444359/TB2j9N5aEafF1Jjy1XbXXaYiXXa_!!1857444359.jpg_100x100.jpg"`

вот так я могу получить:

```
$re = '/data-original=.+.jpg/';
$str = 'data-original="https://img.alicdn.com/imgextra/i3/1857444359/TB2j9N5aEafF1Jjy1XbXXaYiXXa_!!1857444359.jpg"';
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);
var_dump($matches);
```

но мне наоборот добавить после `.jpg`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проверяйте позицию, в которой строка заканчивается кавычкой, и производите замену в этой позиции, с последующей подстановкой последнего символа в этой строке. Звучит запутано, поэтому публикую пример:

```
$string = 'data-original="https://img.alicdn.com/imgextra/i3/1857444359/TB2j9N5aEafF1Jjy1XbXXaYiXXa_!!1857444359.jpg"';

echo preg_replace('~(")$~', '_100x100.jpg$1', $string);
```

Результат :

```
data-original="https://img.alicdn.com/imgextra/i3/1857444359/TB2j9N5aEafF1Jjy1XbXXaYiXXa_!!1857444359.jpg_100x100.jpg"
```

Comment: Cпасибо. Как вариант хороший но я сделал чуть по другому.

Answer (score 1):

Вот как то так у меня получилось =)

```
$string = 'data-original="https://img.alicdn.com/imgextra/i3/1857444359/TB2j9N5aEafF1Jjy1XbXXaYiXXa_!!1857444359.jpg"';

echo preg_replace('/.jpg/', '.jpg_320x320.jpg', $string);
```